# How to place controls at the bottom of the page in MAUI

Tags: maui

I have this XAML page:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TimeApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="TimeApp.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Helpers"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="25">
        <Label Text="¡ Hola, Juan Pérez !" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Text="Empresa S.A." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Margin="0, 22, 10, 0" FontFamily="FontAwesomeRegular" Text="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Calendar}"></Label>
            <Label Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" Text="Martes, 6 de junio de 2023" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Grid Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" 
              ColumnDefinitions="*, *" 
              RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto">
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Turno actual" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="08:00 a 19:00" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hora de llegada" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="07:55" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Horas trabajadas" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="5 h 20 m" />
        </Grid>
        <HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Gray">
            <Button Text="Entrada" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <Button Text="Salida" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I am trying to place the "Entrada" and "Salida" buttons at the bottom of the page, but no avail.

How can I do it? I tried with `VerticalOptions`. Adding other `StackLayout` before the `HorizontalStackLayout` but it did not work.

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Forms : How to make button appear at the bottom of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901989/xamarin-forms-how-to-make-button-appear-at-the-bottom-of-a-page)

Comment: the linked answer is for Xamarin Forms but the same idea should apply in MAUI

Comment: *"I tried with VerticalOptions"* - VerticalOptions on the inner HorizontalStackLayout only tells it what to do *relative to its parent*. You also have to tell the parent (and parent of parent, etc, if that exists) to fill all the height. Put `VerticalOptions="Fill"` on `VerticalStackLayout`, which is the parent.

Comment: @Jason Yes.. that worked. and what about button alignments? if "Entrada" should be on the left and "Salida" to the right. My `HorizontalOptions` did not work. Should I use Grid instead? or is there other option?

Comment: as @ToolmakerSteve points out, a stack layout will not automatically fill its parent if you do not tell it to.

Comment: *"My HorizontalOptions did not work"* - for the exact same reason that you had trouble vertically, except horizontally: you need `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` on the parent (HorizontalStackLayout) of the buttons. And you might also need to add that to grandparent (VerticalStackLayout). Or use columns of a grid; either solution is fine.

Comment: @Jason I have used `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` in parent of buttons (`HorizontalStackLayout`) and "Entrada" button with `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` and "Salida" button with `HorizontalOptions="End"`.  It does not work. Since parent has a fill, I don't understand why buttons are not placed correctly. I tried with `StartAndExpand` in the "Entrada" button, but without success.

Comment: note that in MAUI a Grid is the suggested layout to use for this kind of page.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/layouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Grid layout, Below is the modified code

```
 <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                         Padding="25">
        <Label Text="¡ Hola, Juan Pérez !"
               FontSize="20"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Text="Empresa S.A."
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Margin="0, 22, 10, 0"
                   FontFamily="FontAwesomeRegular"
                   Text="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Calendar}"></Label>
            <Label Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
                   Text="Martes, 6 de junio de 2023" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Grid Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
              ColumnDefinitions="*, *"
              RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto">
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Turno actual" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="08:00 a 19:00" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Hora de llegada" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="07:55" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Horas trabajadas" />
            <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="5 h 20 m" />
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                           BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <Button Text="Entrada"
                BackgroundColor="Green"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Button Text="Salida"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</Grid>
```