# Creating MAUI wizard control

Tags: maui

I am creating a wizard control in MAUI. On of the screens is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Helpers"
             x:Class="TimeApp.Controls.Wizard.Steps.SetupWizardWelcomeView">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Label 
                Text="¡ Bienvenido a su enrolamiento !"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="0, 20, 0, 20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label 
                Text="Por medio de este asistente, podrá darse de alta en el sistema de control de asistencia de su empresa" />
        </StackLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *" BackgroundColor="red">
                <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Text="Anterior" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Button.ImageSource>
                            <FontImageSource
                                FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid"
                                Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Previous}"
                                Color="DodgerBlue"
                                Size="24"/>
                        </Button.ImageSource>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <Button.ImageSource>
                            <FontImageSource
                                FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid"
                                Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Next}"
                                Color="DodgerBlue"
                                Size="24"/>
                        </Button.ImageSource>
                        <Button.Text>Siguente</Button.Text>
                    </Button>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

I am not getting the page to look how I need.

First, I need the buttons to be placed at the bottom of the page and second, to place the `FontAwesomeIcons.Next` icon to the right of the button label.

How can I do that? I have already spent several hours trying to do this but no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place controls at the bottom of the page in MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76418878/how-to-place-controls-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-maui)

Comment: You already asked a question specifically about placing buttons at the bottom of a page and were given a detailed answer **which you accepted**.  Why are you not utilizing that here?

Comment: That does not work in this case. The exact same code does not show the buttons at bottom. The only difference is that the other was a ContentPage and this one is a ContentView because it is inside a custom control I am creating. On the other hand, this question has something different. Please read last paragraphs.

Comment: Grid is the MS recommended solution.  I can’t see why it wouldn’t work in a ContentView

Comment: If this is inside a custom control, then all it can do is place buttons at bottom of that control, not at bottom of containing page. Set a backgroundcolor on the contentview, and you'll likely find that it does not extend all the way to bottom of screen. Am I right? If so, then you'll need to show the xaml of the page in which you use the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to place the FontAwesomeIcons.Next icon to the right of the button label.

To achieve this, you may use `ContentLayout` property which defines the object that controls the position of the button image and the spacing between the button's image and text.

So you want to place the icon the right of the text, try the following:

```
<Button WidthRequest="200" Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" Text="Anterior" ContentLayout="Right,1">
```

The "1" stands for the spacing between the text and the image.

To place the button at the bottom, just as @Jason said, using a grid can achieve this, though you use a custom control. The solution is the similar.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             ...
             >

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            ......
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <local:CustomControl Grid.Row="1"/> // your custom control/ContentView
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Hope it works